# Jagged 3D array creation in C

Tags: c, jagged-arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a dynamic 3D array using C.
the idea is to create a 3D array which looks like something like this

```
A[0][128][128]
A[1][64][64]
A[2][32][32]
A[3][16][16]
A[4][8][8]
.....
A[n][1][1]
```

n,128,128 are the inputs.

can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: That's not a jagged array, if the sub-dimensions are all constant size.  Just say `new AType[n][128][128]`, surely? See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/62512 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902055

Comment: I just used sub-dimensions same as an example, they can be different in the actual program. sorry for not making that clear. Anyways, got it working now..

@unwind: yeah, its kind of mip-map i guess..Actually I was writing a code for multi grid method. A was the matrix that stores all the values for different grids

Answer (score 0):

The following function allocates the memory for your dynamic array. `elem_size` is the size for each element, `n` refers to the size of the first dimension, the other two dimensions are sized `128`.

```
void* create_3Darray(size_t elem_size, size_t n) {
    return malloc(elem_size * n * 128 * 128);
}
```

Usage:

```
int ***arr = create_3Darray(sizeof(int), 256);
arr[2][5][12] = 12;
```

You can substitute `malloc` with `calloc` to initialize the elements to `0`, otherwise the array might be filled with random values.

Also you should be careful not to read/write over the arrays/dimensions bounds.

Comment: If I am understanding right, I will still have a 3D array like

arr[0][5][12] ; arr[1][5][12] ; arr[2][5][12] ..so in this case I still have a 5X12 2D array for each arr[n]

What I am trying to do is probably a jagged 3D array

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is a simple 3D array, and not jagged. For a jagged array you'd need size information for each sub-array which has to be passed to the allocation function.

Comment: Got it working, had to change the dims inside the for loops. Thanks